# CloseableHttpAsyncClient - Requests per second capping out at 10k/s?

Tags: java, performance, http

I have an application where I'd like to send out at least 100k http requests per second with a message size of around 2kb give or take. But I cannot seem to send any faster than 10k per second.

I have prebuilt all of the requests to be made to ensure I am not throttling myself in the construction phase. Here is what the sending portion looks like-

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients
        .custom()
        .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(1000)
        .build();

client.start();

ArrayList<Future<HttpResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<HttpPost> requests = new ArrayList<>();

/* ... I build 100k requests ... */

for(HttpPost request : requests) {
  futures.add(client.execute(request, null));
}

/* ... record start time ... */

for(Future future : futures) {
  future.get();
}

/* ... print change since start time ... */
```

I've adjusted the MaxConnTotal and it doesn't appear to get any faster after 1000. I've also tested different server sizes with cores ranging from 4 to 72, and network speeds ranging from 5gbps to 10gbps. Even on those 72 core 10gbps machines going above 1000 MaxConnTotal doesn't seem to help.

It doesn't matter the size of the machine it seems. Big or small it always takes about 10s to send 100k requests.

I've also tried setting the ulimit higher, and setting `nofiles` in `/etc/security/limits.conf` to unlimited for both * and root (and of course rebooting afterwards).

What am I missing? Why can't I achieve 100k requests per second on all this hardware with an NIO http client?

Comment: The cap could be around the thread pool, check out [this](https://www.baeldung.com/httpasyncclient-tutorial).

Comment: The IOReactor configured for the HttpAsyncClient manages the threads. The IOReactor can handle many connections per thread using the event pattern. See NIO

Comment: I think you should call HttpUtils.consume for response body, and then close response